# PHP Regex in repetition

Tags: regex

Is there a way to catch matches in a repetition in PHP?

```
<?php
$data = array();
preg_match_all("/^([\d]{1,2}?)(([\d]{2}))*([\d]{3})$/is", "987654321", $data);
print_r($data);
```

Output of:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 987654321
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 98
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 54
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 54
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 321
    )

)
```

There is an error in [2]nd index.
Expected outputs are:

- Last 3 digits.
- Then every 2 digits from last.
- The very first catch could be of 1 or 2 digits, or missing as well.
- Input can be of any length.

For example **987654321** should catch 98, 76, 54, 321, while **87654321** will do 8, 76, 54, 321.

Comment: For the length of these numbers, you could try [`(\d+)(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{3})$`](https://regex101.com/r/UXqzsq/1/). The last group will contain 3 numbers, then 2 numbers, 2 numbers, and all before in the first group.

Comment: If you're using C# they have a capture collection that can get `( \d{2} )*` individual captures in a open ended quantified capture group. Otherwise, capture group gets overwritten on each _quantified_ pass. If that's fuzzy, let me know.

Comment: Reverse the number and use [`(?:^(\d{3})|\G(?!\A))(\d{1,2})`](https://regex101.com/r/T7fOaJ/1). The issue is that you can't capture the same group multiple times in PHP and the only way you can do that is using `\G`, but then the problem is that using variable length expressions (in your case) won't work without wizardry, so just flip the string and use the regex in this comment.

Comment: Another option is to use [`(?:^(\d(?=(?:\d{2})+\d$)|\d{2})|\G(?!\A))(\d{2}(?:\d$)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/T7fOaJ/3) (this is the wizardry I was talking about in my previous comment)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [`^(\d{1,2})((?:\d{2})+)(\d{3})$`](https://regex101.com/r/T7fOaJ/4) and then just use `str_split($x, 2)` on the second capture group to get every 2 chars

Comment: A single regex solution: [`(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\d+$))(?:(?:^\d{1,2}|\d{2})(?=(?:\d{2})*\d{3}$)|\d{3}$)`](https://regex101.com/r/5hXiD3/1). It validates the string and returns the parts as separate matches. This is a "regex hack". Use the solution from the comment above.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [`(?:\G(?!\A)|^(?=\d+$))(\d{1,2}(?=(?:\d{2})*\d{3}$)|\d{3}$)`](https://regex101.com/r/T7fOaJ/5) is faster (no need to capture `\d{1,2}` and `\d{2}` separately if it's greedy. The first capture will ensure all following are exactly 2 digits)

Comment: @ctwheels That pattern follows the same logic, just the optmized version.